# Uploading the latest file version from a folder

Tags: r, import, timestamp, export

When I export files from R, I add a timestamp. I created some example data below

```
library(readxl)

mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$carb <- NULL

timestamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%d %m %Y %Hh")
timestamp <- gsub(" ", "_", timestamp)
write_xlsx(mtcars, path = paste0(path_in, "mtcars_timestamp_", timestamp, ".xlsx"), col_names = TRUE)
write_xlsx(mtcars2, path = paste0(path_in, "mtcars_timestamp_", timestamp, ".xlsx"), col_names = TRUE)
timestamp <- "07_12_2022_11h"
write_xlsx(mtcars, path = paste0(path_in, "mtcars_timestamp_", timestamp, ".xlsx"), col_names = TRUE)
timestamp <- "06_12_2022_13h"
write_xlsx(mtcars2, path = paste0(path_in, "mtcars2_timestamp_", timestamp, ".xlsx"), col_names = TRUE)
```

The downside of this approach is that I have to update the files names when I load them into R.

I was wondering if there is a way to make R automatically upload the latest version of a file.

Desired_output:

```
mtcars2 <- read_xlsx("mtcars2_timestamp_06_12_2022_10h.xlsx")
mtcars <- read_xlsx("mtcars_timestamp_07_12_2022_11h.xlsx")
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the '%Y%m%d%H' format for the time stamp, so that files can be sorted lexicographically and you would have no need to parse the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fs package to take a look at your file structure and pull the file with the most recent upload date. Then dynamically run this result through your read_xlsx function.

```
# Install and load the "fs" package
install.packages("fs")
library(fs)

path = "/path/to/directory"

# Get the modification time for each file
files = dir_ls(path)

# Get the modification times for each file
times = file.info(files)$mtime

# Find the index of the file with the latest modification time
index = which.max(times)

# Print the name of the latest file
print(files[index])

read.xlsx(files[index])
```